# Spring OAuth2 Requiring PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on integrating Spring Security OAuth2 with JWT tokens into a Spring Boot project. My authentication server is configured similar to what is found in this [sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jwt/src/main/java/demo/Application.java).

When the OAuth2 client performs the POST on `/oauth/token` it is unable to create the access token. The specific error logged is:

`o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined`

I've debugged it down to `AbstractTokenGranter` line 70 at the call to `tokenServices.createAccessToken`. I've not been able to easily debug further than that because this call actually goes through a proxy. It seems something in the configuration is wanting to make this transactional. Creating access tokens shouldn't be transactional in JWT. I could see why retrieving the access code would be transactional, but the code successfully gets past that point.

Why might this be requiring the `PlatformTransactionManager` and how can I supply one?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you configured in your application a usage of a in-memory database with `new InMemoryTokenStore()`, but your spring-boot application contains no in-memory database.

Solution: add in your spring-boot pom or gradle dependency a in-memory database.

Example for H2 and Maven pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.187</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not using any SQL database.

Comment: Question:
Where do you store your registered clients?

Comment: One more hint for you. 
The spring internal spring implementation for the default DefaultTokenService is annotated with @Transactional (line 81). Than you need any kind of transaction manager. 
I see two soloution for you. Implement a your own TokenService without Transactional annotation or add a in a in memeory database as dependency.

Comment: It ha nothing to do with suppliying an in-memory database. Sprin Oauth InMemory implementations use a Map to store key and values.

Comment: @FlorianE. I'd like to store authorities within a separate table, but `getAccessToken` in `DefaultTokenService` is not annotated with `@Transactional`. Therefore I get a lazy initialization exceptions, do you know if there is any reason for not proxying the get method?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

tokenServices.createAccessToken use @Transactional .
As i use mongo DB i don't need transactions .

i solved the problem by adding a PseudoTransactionManager bean .

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return new PseudoTransactionManager();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that methods in DefaultTokenServices are annotated with @Transactional. So even if you're not using a database, you'll need to add a transaction manager bean like this in your authorization server configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourceTransactionManager() {
            @Override
            public Object getResourceFactory() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {

            }

            @Override
            public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {

            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue of PlatformTransactionManager and resolved it by the following steps:

1. Added H2 database to `pom.xml` (to enable storage of clients in memory)
2. Using Mongo DB as application backend. (ensured application uses MongoRepository instead of CrudRepository)
3. Removed exclude class in `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation (I had earlier added `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in exclusion)

Point 1 and Point 3 are mutual. H2 configuration should have DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class enabled.

Thanks.