# Creating a new token in Spring-Security throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for PlatformTransactionManager bean in main project but not in prototype

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

We're adding an OAuth2 authorization server via spring-boot-security-oauth2 to an existing spring boot project. The project uses Jetty as the servlet container, and MongoDB as a database.

We created a prototype of the authorization server using the same specifications and it worked out fine, however, when we move the prototype code into the main project, we get a server error on any valid client request for a new token with the following log output:

> 2016-09-30 10:00:40.938 DEBUG 622 --- [qtp583896770-19] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined

My question is: 
**What is the cause of the difference in behavior, and how do we fix it?**

Stepping through the code with the debugger shows that Spring security successfully looks up the client and throws this exception when it tries to create a new token. The `DefaultTokenServices`, which we're using in both the prototype and the main project, are annotated with `@Transactional`, which requires a `PlatformTransactionManager`.

In both cases we're using `@SpringBootApplication` so we're relying on the implicit autoconfiguration to create a `PlatformTransactionManager` for us, which seems to be working in the prototype, but not in the main project; although, interestingly, when we print a list of beans registered in the application context, no bean implementing `PlatformTransactionManager` shows up in either case.

**EDIT:**
It does appear that we can add our own PlatformTransactionManager bean to the configuration, and that we will avoid the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, however we'd like to use auto-configuration where possible and avoid implementing our own beans.

For reference, here is a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171418/spring-oauth2-requiring-platformtransactionmanager) that has no selected answer so far, but has possibly related information. The code base of the main project is pretty large; following are what I believe to be the relevant files:

```
package com.unifiedcontrol.security.oauth2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2TokenStore oAuth2TokenStore;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientDetailsService oAuth2ClientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(oAuth2TokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(oAuth2ClientDetailsService);
    }
}

/**
 * CODE CREDIT: https://github.com/Ekito/spring-multitenancy
 * A MongoDB implementation of the TokenStore.
 */
@Service
public class OAuth2TokenStore implements TokenStore {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AccessTokenRepository oAuth2AccessTokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RefreshTokenRepository oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository;

    private AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator = new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();

    public OAuth2TokenStore() {}

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        return readAuthentication(token.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(String tokenId) {
        return oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByTokenId(tokenId).getAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken oAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken = new OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken(token,
                authentication, authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication));
        oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.save(oAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String tokenValue) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken token = oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByTokenId(tokenValue);
        if(token == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return token.getoAuth2AccessToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken accessToken = oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByTokenId(token.getValue());
        if(accessToken != null) {
            oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.delete(accessToken);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void storeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.save(new OAuth2AuthenticationRefreshToken(refreshToken, authentication));
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2RefreshToken readRefreshToken(String tokenValue) {
        return oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.findByTokenId(tokenValue).getoAuth2RefreshToken();
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken token) {
        return oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.findByTokenId(token.getValue()).getAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken token) {
        oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.delete(oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.findByTokenId(token.getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAccessTokenUsingRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken) {
        oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.delete(oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByRefreshToken(refreshToken.getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken token =  oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByAuthenticationId(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication));
        return token == null ? null : token.getoAuth2AccessToken();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientId(String clientId) {
        List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> tokens = oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
        return extractAccessTokens(tokens);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientIdAndUserName(String clientId, String userName) {
        List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> tokens = oAuth2AccessTokenRepository.findByClientIdAndUserName(clientId, userName);
        return extractAccessTokens(tokens);
    }

    private Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> extractAccessTokens(List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> tokens) {
        List<OAuth2AccessToken> accessTokens = new ArrayList<OAuth2AccessToken>();
        for(OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken token : tokens) {
            accessTokens.add(token.getoAuth2AccessToken());
        }
        return accessTokens;
    }
}

/**
 * CODE CREDIT: https://github.com/Ekito/spring-multitenancy
 * Spring Data MongoDB repository for the OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken entity.
 */
public interface OAuth2AccessTokenRepository extends MongoRepository<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken, String> {
    OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByTokenId(String tokenId);

    OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByRefreshToken(String refreshToken);

    OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByAuthenticationId(String authenticationId);

    List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> findByClientIdAndUserName(String clientId, String userName);

    List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> findByClientId(String clientId);
}

@RestController
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer {

}
```